# Java Array Parameter and Array Type Metot

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

I started learning java. But experiencing problems now.

I'm use to array type method but this method parameters is not array.

```
public static int carpma[] (int [] dizi)
```

incorrectly, as I encode above.

that is, if the method is not the type of array parameter range. However, if the method is not the type of array parameter can be an array. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is really obscure, it is very difficult to understand you. Please improve it

Comment: Please, re-write your question, impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, your method signature

```
public static int carpma[] (int [] dizi)
```

should be

```
public static int[] carpma (int[] dizi)
```

which is a method that takes an `int[]` and returns an `int[]`. You could also use [`varargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) like

```
public static int[] carpma (int... dizi) // <-- dizi is still accessed like an
                                         //     int[]
```

and then you can pass in an `int[]` or multiple individual `int` values.

```
int[] arr = carpma(1,2,3);
```